# Do pcb manufacturers solder components as well?

Tags: pcb

Let's say I have all the Gerber files generated in Eagle and I send them to a manufacturer. Do pcb manufacturers like 4pcb or seeedstudio usually solder your components as well or do they just send you the pcb only and you will have to order and solder parts yourself? If the former how do you send them the parts info? If the latter are there any manufacturers that also assemble your components?

Comment: Yes.  Contact the manufacturers, ask what services they can provide.  When a supplier does provide a particular service, it's usually mentioned on their web site (in large letters).

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't agree with the unilateral closing. It's not the best question, but the close reason simply doesn't apply.

Comment: @Matt  What reason would you recommend?  How about "insufficient preliminary research" ?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I'd recommend leaving it alone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30317/discussion-on-question-by-ace-do-pcb-manufacturers-solder-components-as-well).

Comment: I don't think this question is asking for recommendations for specific products or where to buy them. It's simply asking if some manufacturers do. I do not think this question should have been put on hold.
To answer the question, you would send the manufacturer the design files as well as a bill of materials. Often you'll also want pick-and-place files so that their machines know where to place each component, and other assembly notes. Board assembly will cost a little bit more on top of the board fabrication.

Answer (score 2):

Some board houses also do assembly. If it's not on their website, simply ask them. They will tell you what they need, and give you any instructions for components you need to supply. A lot of times they will run some kind of special, where you get some deal on assembly for buying boards from them. That said, there are usually NRE costs associated with assembly and it really doesn't make sense to do this for just a few boards.

Comment: Web search for `contract manufacturing` as this is the term they use to advertise this service.

Comment: You might also search for [Electronics Manufacturing Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics_manufacturing_services) (EMS)

Comment: Tooling costs for PCA would be costly for a hobbyist, expect a few hundred dollars for the solder stencils.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some PCB manufacturing companies do provide PCB assembly services. What you should pay attention to is whether they are following the strict quality requirement procedure, including IPC standards.